# How to get the full image URL on iOS with UIImagePickerController using new PHAsset stuff

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, phasset

How the heck do you get the full image URL on iOS with UIImagePickerController using new PHAsset stuff, since the ALAssetLibrary stuff was deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

I was having an awful time finding the answer to this, so to help people in the future, here is my code that works to get the actual file URL to a photo selected with the built-in iOS UIImagePickerController. Still a little nervous about using the ALAsset URL to get the PHAsset, if you know of another way to do that then by all means please share.

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
NSURL* sourceURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
if (sourceURL != nil) {
    PHAsset* asset = [[PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[sourceURL] options:nil] lastObject];

    PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions* assetOptions = [[PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions alloc] init];
    [assetOptions setNetworkAccessAllowed:false];
    [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:assetOptions 
        completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput* contentEditingInput, NSDictionary* info) {
        NSURL* fullImageURL = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;
        printf("Hey, got the actual image URL: %s\n", [[fullImageURL absoluteString] UTF8String]);
        }];
    }

// ...finish and dismiss the UIImagePickerController
}
```